# 2 inch black bar on the left side of display?

Tags: 14.04, intel, display-resolution, ubuntu-studio, integrated

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 14.04 LTS with Xfce environment, and there is a 2 inch black bar on the left of my display, and it pushes everything to the right as well.

I installed it on an older machine that has integrated Intel graphics. It also sticks when it is at the loading screen, regardless of the desktop resolution. I changed it to a lower resolution and it is gone now, but at the loading screen it is still there. The maximum resolution on my monitor being 1440x900 with a VGA connection. I went to the display settings and it had two 1440x900 options for some reason. I clicked the other one and the black bar goes away, but there ends up being one at the bottom of the page, and it pushes the menu bar up, to where I can barely see it. Right now I'm using 1152x864 resolution right now and I don't have any issues, but I would like to use my full resolution.

It is even this way with the regular Ubuntu 14.04 that uses Unity interface, the live USB version or otherwise.

Is there any way I can fix this?

[image: See the bar on the left? It pushes everything to the right.]

Comment: A screenshot will likely help us understand the situation quicker.

Comment: Can you please include the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in your question for more information?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, well that was embarrassingly easy. All I had to do was auto adjust my monitor!

Comment: That is pretty funny.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Luke's great answer, I had read this and didn't really link "auto adjust my monitor" to what eventually helped me which was a small button on the monitor called "scale source" since at least on the display settings, nvidia-settings etc everything seemed adjusted fine.  I had two side black bars, one on each side and fell down the xrandr threads for far too long.